# cxfreeze (or equivalent) and cross build?

Tags: python

Is it possible for cx_freeze (or any other tool with the same purpose) to cross build binaries? I.e. build Windows binary on a Linux PC? Or is this too much to ask?

I tried with cx_freeze and got the following:

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Win32GUI
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you install Python etc. inside Wine, cx_Freeze will run, but it misses out some key DLLs. So no. If building on Windows isn't an option, you can work out the DLLs that it requires, and manually copy them into the build directory after running cx_Freeze.

(Technical note: If anyone has the know-how to work on Wine, I believe the BindImageEx function in imagehlp.dll needs to be implemented for this to work)